# How to show custom messages in a dialog box in Win32 API?

Tags: c++, winapi

**How to show custom messages using a dialog box in Win32 API** rather than show them in a default `MessageBox` function?

I made a function as follows:

```
void DialogBox_Custom (HWND hWndParent, LPSTR contentToShow)
{   
HWND hDialog = CreateDialog(GetModuleHandle(NULL), MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_DIALOG1), hWndParent, DialogProc);
if (!IsWindowVisible(hDialog))
{
    ShowWindow(hDialog, SW_SHOW);
}
SetDlgItemText(hDialog, IDC_EDIT1, contentToShow);
}
```

But when I call this function, the dialog box is appearing like millions of times per second and never ending until I close the program by force.

Please kindly someone help me make a custom dialog box where I can show some content sent from the parent window to an `EDIT` control window in the dialog box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`DialogBoxParam`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645465%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function to create the modal (suspend execution until the window is closed) dialog box.

```
DialogBoxParam(instance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_YOURDIALOG), hWndParent, YourWndProc, (LPARAM)contentToShow);
```

You then have to create a function YourWndProc to handle the messages to paint and offer a mechanism to close the window, to allow execution to continue after your DialogBox() call.

```
INT_PTR CALLBACK YourWndProc(HWND hDlg, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_INITDIALOG:
        SetDlgItemText(hDlg, IDC_EDIT1, (LPSTR)lParam);
        return (INT_PTR)TRUE;
    case WM_CLOSE:
        EndDialog(hDlg, LOWORD(wParam));
        break;
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hDlg, message, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Comment: And to process a button if you have one on your dialog, use a message type WM_COMMAND, and a BN_CLICKED notification code, and the ID of the button in your resource, and then just call EndDialog() again

Answer (score -1):

Modal dialogs are similar to `MessageBox`: your code gets control back when the dialog is closed. API: `DialogBox`, `DialogBoxIndirect`.

Modeless dialogs are similar to windows: you create them with the help of dialog templates and you get the control back immediately, they live powered by message dispatch. This is what you do but you expect them to act as if they were modal. API: `CreateDialog`, `CreateDialogIndirect`.

With both modal and modeless dialog you control the dialog with your own `DialogProc` and you create the dialog with resource dialog template, which automatically creates controls (and you, of course, can add control in code).